# Will Hardware prefetcher detect this?

Tags: caching, operating-system, performance-testing, cpu-architecture

Will hardware prefetcher detect the stride and prefetch the block in the following scenario?

CASE 1 : I am generating unique random no(non-repeating) and make a list of those random no. Now, by using those random no in the list, I am accessing array at that position. So as there is no fixed stride in a single iterations, hardware prefetcher won't be able to prefetch a block in advance.

Now, if I use same random sequence of random no for multiple iterations  ,in a single iterations hardware prefetcher won't be able to find a stride, but for multiple iterations I am using same sequence.

So , **my question** is, will hardware prefetcher detect my repeated use of sequence( generated in random fashion) and prefetch a block ?

**Can I generate a random sequence ONCE and use the same sequence for multiple Iterations ?** **Can I use this approach to prevent hardware prefetcher to detect a stride ?**

**OR, Should I generate random no in every iterations ?**

Comment: It depends on the hardware. Read the spec sheet for your CPU.

Comment: Unless your sequence is quite small, this is highly unlikely, as pre-fetch circuits have fairly limited buffers to play with to detect patterns. But, as @RaymondChen mentions, pre-fetch circuits are also very highly variable, depending on the exact hardware, and even among generations of the same hardware, so check the documentation and benchmark...

Comment: Thanks Raymond and twalberg, for quick reply. Actually I am generating 1024/4096 random numbers and planning to use either ODD or EVEN numbers or ALL. In that case, will it exceed buffer size of prefetcher ?

Comment: The prefetcher buffer size is dependent on the CPU, and you still haven't said what CPU you are using. This is like asking "How many phone numbers can I store in my cell phone?" without telling us what cell phone you're using.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using Intel Core2Duo 2.20GHz system, with Fedora OS.